# How to read external JSON file from JMeter

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Is there a way (any jmeter plugin) by which we can have the JMeter script read all the contents(String) from external text file ?

I have a utility in java which uses Jackson ObjectMapper to convert a arraylist to string and puts it to a text file in the desktop. The file has the JSON info that i need to send in the jmeter Post Body.

I tried using ${__FileToString()} but it was unable to deserialize the instance of java.util.ArrayList. It was also not reading all the values properly.

I am looking for something like csv reader where i just give the file location. I need all the json info present in the file. Need to extract it and assign to the post body.

Thanks for your help !!!

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about how to deserialize ArrayList in JMeter and dynamically build request body, you can use i.e. [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) for it.

1. Add a Beanshell PreProcessor as a child of your request
2. Put the following code into the PreProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("/path/to/your/serialized/file.ser");
   ObjectInput oin = new ObjectInputStream(in);
   ArrayList list = (ArrayList) oin.readObject();
   oin.close();
   in.close();

   for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
       sampler.addArgument("param" + i, list.get(i).toString());
   }
   ```

The code will read file as ArrayList, iterate through it and add request parameter like:

```
param1=foo
param2=bar
etc.
```

This is the closest answer I'm able to provide, if you need more exact advice - please elaborate your question. In the meantime I recommend you to get familiarized with [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide to learn about scripting in JMeter and what do pre-defined variables like "sampler" in above code snippet mean.

Comment: Thanks for replying. 
I was getting arraylist error when i was trying to use ${__FileToString()}. I dont have to iterate as i need the entire JSON info present in the file.

Comment: If you have plain text file containing JSON payload it shouldn't be a problem to read it via __FileToString() function. Can you post *jmeter.log* file output?

Comment: thanks it started working !!! the problem was with the contents of the JSON. Once i fixed that one, fileToString worked